# How long can a Firebase Realtime Database connection stay alive as a stream?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, timeout

I am building an IoT project with Firebase.

Everything works fine, but after some hours it gets disconnected.

I'm not sure if this is a network problem or a Firebase limit. So is there a limit of time that a stream can stay alive in Firebase Realtime Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected that the connection may occasionally be reset from the server, either because of something between your client and the server, or because operations on the server.

The Firebase SDKs will normally handle this by reconnecting, and restoring their state on the new connection. Since the library you're using is based on the REST API, and not on an SDK, either that library or your application code will have to handle reconnecting after a connection reset.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase keeps the connection alive and tries to reconnect when the connection drops. The issue might be the internet connection or the device shutting down socket connections. You can try logging the error to find the issue:

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   ....
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: I am using c++ on the device.

Comment: @NicholasSanti sorry. I don't know c++ but here's how firebase error logging should work in c++ : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#value-callbacks

Comment: I am using this library https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266